# MySQL get latest conversation messages

Tags: mysql, sql, database, chat

I'm making an app where users can chat to other users (1 on 1, NOT a group chat). I have a MySQL table that stores all the messages from every user, like:

```
from_id   to_id          message             time
abc123    def456         Hello               789
def456    abc123         What's up?          1234`
def456    abc123         How was last night? 2345
abc123    p0tat0         I missed the bus    3456
def456    p0tat0         I hate you :(       4567`
def456    another_user   I hate Potato!      5678`
```

How can I get the latest message from AND to `abc123` sorted from newest to oldest, like:

**`from_id             to_id               message             time`**

`abc123              p0tat0              I missed the bus    3456`

`def456              abc123              How was last night? 2345`

`time` will always be in an ascending order in the messages table if that matters.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you ^.^

`SELECT *,`**`'from' as direction`**`FROM messages WHERE from_username='admin' AND 'time' = ( SELECT MAX('time') FROM messages WHERE from_username='admin'`**`OR to_username='admin'`**`)`

`UNION ALL`

`SELECT *,`**`'to' as direction`**`FROM messages WHERE to_username='admin' AND 'time' = ( SELECT MAX('time') FROM messages WHERE`**`to_username='admin' OR`**`to_username='admin' )`

Comment: "time will always be in an ascending order" Rows have no order in relational databases, so this statement is both incorrect and irrelevant!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM
messageTable
WHERE from_id='abc123'
AND `time` = ( SELECT MAX(`time`) FROM messageTable WHERE from_id='abc123' )

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM
messageTable
WHERE to_id='abc123'
AND `time` = ( SELECT MAX(`time`) FROM messageTable WHERE to_id='abc123' )
```

Comment: Also do you think storing every message ever in one massive table is the best idea? Wouldn't it get kinda slow if there were a lot of messages?

Comment: your table structure of message table is fine as you are only storing id's of users in the message table . If users have more details like name, location etc then store it in different table and join the users and message table based on user id's

Comment: you could do an `order by time desc limit 1` rather than subquery

Comment: Thank you yeah I'm only storing user ids in the message table

Comment: @ughai ORDER BY clause cannot be used with before union operator

Comment: @Strawberry I meant not the 1 latest message, but the latest message sent to each friend.

Comment: @Strawberry actually oops sorry strawberry I had to make a slight change so it returns the latest in only one direction and not both (send\recieve)

Comment: @Strawberry I'll put the edited version in my question