# Latest message for every friend using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I found a similar problem here:
*[MySQL get latest conversation messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41095463/mysql-get-latest-conversation-messages)*

However, with the solution I get only the latest message to or from the user.

Well, that's my starting point:

Whenever the user sends a message himself/herself, a database entry is created as follows.

- Sender: ID in column A (own ID)
- Recipient: ID in column B (friend)
- Text: column text

Whenever the user receives a message, a database entry is created as follows.

- Sender: ID in column A (friend)
- Recipient: ID in column B (own ID)
- Text: column text

Now the last message with the time should be output - grouped for each friend.

This is my current code:

```
$query1 = "SELECT Zeit as zeit, Text as msg, 'U1' as chattype, A as friend, ID as id
FROM Nachrichten
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT MAX(ID)
    FROM Nachrichten
    WHERE A = '$person'
    GROUP BY B)
ORDER BY ID DESC";

$query2 = "SELECT Zeit as zeit, Text as msg, 'U2' as chattype, B as friend, ID as id
FROM Nachrichten
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT MAX(ID)
    FROM Nachrichten
    WHERE B = '$person'
    GROUP BY A)
ORDER BY ID DESC";
```

```
$ergebnisa = mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM
(
    ($query1)
    UNION ALL
    ($query2)
) t
ORDER BY t.Zeit DESC LIMIT 5");
```

Problem by example:

- User 1 sends User 2 the message "Hello". (Database: A> 1, B> 2)
- User 2 sends User 1 the message "Good evening". (Database: A> 2, B> A)

Suppose the two messages are the most recent.
The two messages are now displayed as the most recent, although actually only the second message should be displayed, since the message before it is also new, but belongs to the same friend.

Comment: I understand German, but not every reader does. If that part is not supposed to be literal, it ought to be translated (the text, not the SQL).

Comment: Thanks, forgot to translate this part

Comment: This API was deprecated a very long time ago. Just sayin'